# New question approval by other senior person

Tags: discussion, suggestion

In last few days I have noticed many questions which are not actually a question but they are for the promotions of their service or product.

[Where to Buy Cheap Careprost Bimatoprost Ophthalmic Solution Sale?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215527/where-to-buy-cheap-careprost-bimatoprost-ophthalmic-solution-sale)

This is one example of it. This is wrong to share or spam on the StackExchange network.

So can't we have some Question approval process for new user ? Like if they ask question then it should be approved by senior user who have reputation more than 2K(or like any other )?

so what will be benefit, We can avoid such question to be published on the  network.

I posted this just for discussion to avoid such spamming on network.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only about new users. Their post get reviewed as Piyush already said, but you'll still find some spam from time to time.

> yes so my concern or this is just suggection that we may implement **but still some negitive people have down vote it** :)

When I find spam posts, I

- downvote it
- **flag it as spam** (gives another downvote)
- check user profile for similiar answers

So it takes two just people for three downvotes to grey-out answer to make it less attractive. Finally, posts that are flagged as spam (correctly) will be deleted very fast.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a review process for post from new users (**First Post Review**), which is reviewed by at least one reviewer (*privilege awarded to users at 500 rep*). While reviewing, a reviewer can improve post by editing or if reviewer found some thing wrong he/she can flag or vote it to close.

You can always flag such post if you found it spam or promotion only post.

Comment: if there is a process then why such post are still on the network ? any one approves it ?

Comment: approval is not in the process, if it is first post, it is reviewed as mentioned in my answer, while reviewing, a reviewer can improve post by editing or if reviewer found some thing wrong he/she can flag or vote it to close.

Comment: yes so my concern or this is just suggection that we may implement 
but still some negitive people have down vote it :)

Comment: I don't think  approval process needs to be implemented, as such post can be removed by a simple flag. Also approving every new post will increase work load on moderators.

Comment: Okay 
every one have different mindset :) 
I thought this so I posted this suggection